# Comparing reaction tests

Tags: anova, nonparametric, kruskal-wallis-test

I have an experiment where every person needs to take reaction tests when he/she is sober, then when lightly and then heavily intoxicated.

I need to perform a test that tells if the intoxication had effect on the reaction tests on a specific person. (I am NOT testing if the intoxication have effect on the reaction test in general).

The reaction test protocol contains 60 hits in each state. I think these numbers do not follow a normal distribution, so I was planning to use Kruskal-Wallis non-parametric ANOVA. However, two of the assumptions are these:

- all individuals must be selected at random from the population
- all individuals must have equal chance of being selected

Now this is not something that would be true in my case, right? I am not measuring 1000 hits and select 60 of them for each reaction test, but this 60 hits are all my population.

Can I use Kruskal-Wallis?